# Add unimplemented methods in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm trying to implement onCreateOptionsMenu but I can't figure how to implement methods, the CTRL+ I shortcut does not work. Does android studio have the override/unimplemented methods option?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes. Go to where you declared the class and right click on what ever you are extending or implementing. A menu with the "Generate..." option shall appear and a sub-menu with what you are looking for will drop down from there.

Answer (score 8):

1. To override abstract methods in android studio use Ctrl+ I.

2.To check all the methods available in super class use Ctrl+ O.

Answer (score 1):

If you have abstract methods to implement, press `Alt+Enter` over class name to open a wizard.

Otherwise, for overriding a function, just start typing the name of your method (without any access attribute or type), anywhere in your class scope. Then, Android Studio should suggest you overridable methods.